# Кнопка в адаптивном меню не позиционируется, как надо

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Существует `<nav>` в `<header>`, который переходит в колоночный режим (когда ширина экрана меньше 764 пикселей) с кнопкой открытия других элементов меню через кнопку (в примере это `<div class="openMenuCont">`)

Смысл в том, что необходимо эту кнопку разместить справа экрана и поверх главного элемента (который по умолчанию active). Я перепробовал разные способы. В итоге разместил кнопку открытия меню внутри активного `<li>`, добавил у `<li>` `position: relative;`, а у кнопки - `position: absolute;`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* HEADER ============ */

nav.header__nav {
    min-height: 70px;
    background-color: #1156ed;
}

.contact-number {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-text {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar--wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.openMenuCont {
    display: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

a.openMenu {
    display: flex;
    height: 24px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 24px;
}


ul.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li.nav__link {
    flex: 1;
    height: 70px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.awrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

li.nav__link:hover {
    background-color: #0f3ea3;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

li.nav__link > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 764px) {
    .navbar {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .navbar>li:not(.active-link) {
        display: none;
    }
    .openMenuCont {
        justify-self: end;
        align-self: start;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    a.openButton {
        display: flex;
        justify-self: end;
        background: #2629c2;
    }
    ul.navbar.responsive {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    ul.navbar.responsive li.nav__link {
        display: flex;
    }
    li.nav__link {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .awrap {
        height: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-alt.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <nav class="header__nav">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar--wrapper">
       <ul class="navbar" id="navbar">
         <li class="nav__link active-link">
           <div class="awrap">
             <a href="index.php">Главная</a>
           </div>
           <div class="openMenuCont">
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="openMenu" onclick="myFunction()">
               <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UOSBYUh.png" alt="">
             </a>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">Техника</a></div></li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">Цены</a></div></li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">О компании</a></div></li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">Контакты</a></div></li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">Наши работы</a></div></li>
         <li class="nav__link"><div class="awrap"><a href="#">Где мы работаем?</a></div></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<script src="scripts/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnwc43g0/

Comment: P.S позиционирование через absosule не подходит т. к над <nav> находится ещё один блок, который может изменяться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавив к `<div class="openMenuCont">` `position: relative;` `top: 23px;` `right: 5px;` теперь даже при изменении высоты вышестоящего `<nav>` отсчёт идёт от родителя.